# How to add post of custom type to a category with custom type capabilities

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I have created a custom post type 'shows'. And I am using the capabilities argument to create my own custom capabilities. My aim is to have a user (`show_manager`, say) who can only edit/create shows and nothing else.

I have managed this, but the `show_manager` is unable to add their (show) post to a category. The metabox appears, but the choices are disabled. I don't need (in fact don't want) them to be able to create / delete categories, but just to select one they want the show to go into.

I have noticed, giving the `show_manager` the `edit_posts` capability allows them to select a category - but also allows them to edit posts (something I don't want).

How can I give the `show_manager` the ability to assign a category to their term without allowing them to `edit posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this problem. The reason is due to the capabilities argument in the `category` taxonomy. i.e.

```
array(    
    'manage_terms' => 'manage_categories',
    'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories',
    'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts',
);
```

So one work around (though not a very good one - and certainly not for use in plugins!) is to *redefine* the Category taxonomy, mapping the 'assign_terms' to some other capability (maybe a custom defined one). This capability can then be given to anyone who I want to be able to assign categories. See the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).